# magento add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a market place assign product if one product have more then one seller it display all the seller with add to cart also i have ajax cart in my website

**My Form Code:**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form" class="ma">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId(); ?>" name="mpassignproduct_id" class="mpassignproduct_id"/>

<button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>"  class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>">
        <span>
        <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span></button><div>
        <button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
        <span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button></div>

</form>
```

Let us assume i have a 2 seller both seller it showing same product id : **2245**

```
<form class="ma" id="seller_addtocart_form" method="post" action="http://kidsdial.com/ajaxcart/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2tpZHNkaWFsLmNvbS90b3lzYm94LXByZXR0eS1mbG93ZXJzLXNyLmh0bWw,/product/2245/form_key/0QUdo7Xr7yRTOpvE/">
```

so that i added 2 seller product it added 1st seller product only how i fix it

[image]

Comment: As you said that one product can sell by multiple seller . I think you need to add something in parameter that differentiate seller like product/2245/seller/abc and product/2245/seller/xyz

Comment: but buy now it's working fine what type of parameter i need to add

Comment: How product price and product assign to seller so based on the parameter you have the same logic to differentiate add to cart

Comment: can you please tell me how to add seller id on that form  $seller->getMpassignproductId();

Comment: You can check following url to do so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857141/magento-1-9-add-parameter-to-add-to-cart-url

Comment: You also need to edit the ajax cart add action to get that parameter

Comment: i add a different from id based on seller but i don't know how to add dynamic id in ajax

Comment: does it solved you problem ?

Comment: No actually i add dynamic form id based on seller but i don't know how to calll dynamc id in ajax can you please help me that

Comment: Means you are not getting the seller id in add to cart action ?

Comment: yes i add seller id in form